# How to Query Remote Linux/Rasbian System's Hostname

Tags: linux, hostname

I have several Raspberry Pi deployments that I want to be able to remotely query over the network for their hostname.

I've found that if I enable SMB via Samba that I can successfully query with a NetBios lookup. For security reason I would assume not to introduce SMB on these system for the sole purpose of hostname identification.

It should also be noted that these systems are not part of a domain and do not register with DNS.

**Is there any known methods out there that will allow me to query an IP address and return the hostname (as defined in /etc/hostname) of a linux based system?**

Comment: Use ssh to the remote rpi and use a command to retrieve the hostname (hostname, uname -n ...). Secure by design, especially with a key. Or is there something preventing this that isn't in the question?

Comment: I have have about 50 devices connected through WiFi and will receive their IP from DHCP. The devices will move around often and assigning a static IP will get away from the zero touch setup we currently use. I want to be able to scan multiple subnet ranges to find the specific hostname I am looking for then SSH to it.

Comment: My alternative would be to document the MAC address for each device / hostname then search for the MAC when needed. It would be best if I would run a program like AngryIP Scanner each time I was looking for a device.

Comment: Can't you get the information from the DHCP server then? The device can send (or receive) its hostname to (from) it.

Comment: Unfortunately I am using Cisco IOS as the DHCP server and this capability is not supported.

Comment: AB, to expand on your DHCP suggestion. I was checking my wireless management system (I use Ruckus) and it appears that it is capturing the hostname broadcast even though my Cisco router is not recording them. With this I am able to centrally see all hostnames with IPs across all WLANs.                                               On my Raspbery Pi the file, "/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf" has an entry "send host-name = gethostname();" that appears to be responsible for this.      I would still like to find a way to query an IP and get a hostname returned, if this is possible without using SMB.

Comment: If you don't want to use the ssh protocol (which is already installed), you can install a snmp server. OID 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.5 should give the information. avahi/zeroconf mught be an other method which might allow broadcast or multicast. Whatever you do you have to install something to get the hostname. It won't come from a ping.

Comment: @A.B: Technically it could – ICMPv6 has a "[Node Information Query](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4620)" type, and Linux iputils `ping -6 -N name <address>` can query supporting hosts. Of course, nobody implements node information responders...

Comment: @grawity oh good to know

Answer (score 0):

I explored the SNMP route and it looks like that is as good as it will get. I created a bat file that did SNMPGETs on 254 addresses then parsed the results. I used SNMP Softwares tool (snmpsoft.com/shell-tools/snmp-get) to accomplish this in Windows. The min timeout value is 1 second so it takes a couple of mins to run but not an issue, wouldn't want it much lower. 
Thanks AB.